# Unable to return site IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

My site at http://arcrealtyco.com will not load in IE8. I have updated jQuery (1.9.1) and updated Modernizr (2.5.2) running on the site. It works fine in ie9 while using ie8 mode, but on ie8 it will not load. It appears the issue is with our CSS file.

Right now it is a 301k size file that has been concatenated from SCSS. I even tested a minified version that is 131k. nothing.

Any thoughts here?

Within the css file we have Bootstrap, Symbolset our global CSS and a few other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `<footer>`, you have a `<br>` inside of a `<strong>`. Try taking that `<strong>` away so it's just a `<br>` by itself. That made the crash go away for me. I used Windows 7 and the real Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: Wow. I have been banging my head against the wall for an hour now. That did the trick. Thanks.